# Access the Default mail configuration in windows phone development

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried to get the default configured mail address from windows phone. i have searched so many way but i did not get proper solution.
How can we access the default mail id in windows phone development.?

Comment: no, you can't access the phone default email address i think so. may i know, for which reason you have asked this ?

Answer (score 0):

For privacy reasons, the email address is not accessible via the Windows Phone SDK.